# Alternatives to T4 for runtime generation of files in .NET

Tags: .net, code-generation, t4

We have a business requirement to generate metatdata files, most often json or XML, conforming to various schemas, and at runtime by a server application.

T4 appeared to be a great option for this.  The ability to provide parameters at runtime, and combine static text with C# was perfect.  However [MSDN's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126519.aspx) advises against using it in server applications, and also advises that all transformations are performed in serial.

Are there any alternatives to T4 templates, for dynamically generating metadata files based on a text template at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

There are two sides to T4, compile time and runtime. They are based on the same tech but the purpose is rather different. Compile time is to generate code that will get compiled as part of your application. Runtime transforms is what you are looking for here.

What the doc says is that they don't recommend using the compile time one on servers, however, using runtime transformation should be ok. It will itself generate a class that will handle the runtime transformations. The application will be self-contained and not require VS components to perform the transform.

[Run-Time Text Generation with T4 Text Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx).

Comment: Right, I guess it makes sense that compile time transformations on servers aren't recommended, but even still, it seems to advise against transformations except in a single thread, which isn't ideal for us.  I've been meaning to look at whether Razor can be used to do what I described...